# php: why $obj is null in the class

Tags: php

I am completely newbie to php. I was a system (personal use) which was built on php. System has to sends email when a joborder creates/updates. But before email method the object is null. I don't know how to fix this.

```
function AUIEO_SEND_HOOK_EMAIL ($record)
{

    $recruiter=$record["recruiter"];
    $sql="select * from user where user_id='{$recruiter}'";
    $db=DatabaseConnection::getInstance();
    $arrAssoc=$db->getAllAssoc($sql);
    $emailAddress=$arrAssoc[0]["email"];

    debug_to_console( $emailAddress );
    $site_id=$arrAssoc[0]["site_id"];
    debug_to_console( $site_id );
    if($emailAddress)
    {
        $obj=new JobOrders($site_id);
        $obj->load($record["id"]);  /* $obj is here null */             
        $obj->sendTemplateEMail("My Joborder 2", $emailAddress);
        debug_to_console( "email sent" );
    }

    $owner=$record["owner"];
    $sql="select * from user where user_id='{$owner}'";
    $db=DatabaseConnection::getInstance();
    $arrAssoc=$db->getAllAssoc($sql);
    $emailAddress=$arrAssoc[0]["email"];
    $site_id=$arrAssoc[0]["site_id"];
    if($emailAddress)
    {
        $obj=new JobOrders($site_id);
        $obj->load($record["id"]);
        $obj->sendTemplateEMail("My Joborder 2", $emailAddress);
    }
}
```

`$obj` has null value. `JobOrders` class in `./lib/JobOrders.php` location. so I included `include_once('./lib/JobOrders.php');` in the file. still it is not working.

Any clue?

Comment: `$emailAddress` does not influence `$obj` being null. We should need the code of **JobOrders.php**, and the value of `$site_id`.

Comment: Where do you print $obj, and why you think is it null? $obj never be null, if execute if statement (of course, if you do not print before initialized, in this code)

Comment: @trincot here is the code https://codeshare.io/CH54x  for JobOrders.php and https://codeshare.io/394Vs for Modules.php

Comment: @ZlatkoHristov I have printed in file. like this `$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w");  fwrite($myfile, $obj); fclose($myfile); `

Comment: @AdamJeffers I already checked `$emailAddress` and it is fine. It has value. sendTemplateEmail was not called.

Comment: value of `$site_id`?

Comment: Yeh ignore my previous comment... see @trincot comment. Provide us the code in JobOrders.php and value of $site_id

Comment: @trincot `$site_id` is value 1.

Comment: @AdamJeffers shared code in comments.

Comment: And you don't have any errors during the execution of `new JobOrders`? It is very unlikely you get a `null` returned from a `new` operator. Could you `var_dump($obj)` immediately after the `new` to be absolutely sure?

Comment: I place `var_dump`. I don't think that will showup on screen. from edit page I submitted then immediately I can view page of it.

Comment: Well you seem to have a working `debug_to_console`, so use that then instead of `var_dump`, as follows: `debug_to_console(json_encode($obj));`

Comment: @trincot `debug` thing is not worked. but I dumped `$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w"); fwrite($myfile, json_encode($obj)j); fclose($myfile);` I see the data now. But why sendTemplateEMail has been not called?

Comment: Well, you have misinformed us in claiming that `$obj` is null. Please update your question with the new information and new question.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of $emailAddress? Your if statement seems to do nothing. You have to compare your variable to something that either ends up as a true or a false (or 1 or 0). Your if always fails now because it is never a "true".

What I think you are trying to do is the following. Checking if the e-mail address is set. You can use the function [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) for that wich will return true if the variable is set (and thus enter the if statement) and otherwise return false.

Try this:

```
if(isset($emailAddress)){
    $obj=new JobOrders($site_id);
    $obj->load($record["id"]);  /* $obj is here null */             
    $obj->sendTemplateEMail("My Joborder 2", $emailAddress);
    debug_to_console( "email sent" );
}
```

And:

```
 if(isset($emailAddress)) {
    $obj=new JobOrders($site_id);
    $obj->load($record["id"]);
    $obj->sendTemplateEMail("My Joborder 2", $emailAddress);
 }
```

Als you should read up a little bit about [if statements](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) in php .

Comment: This really belongs in the comments section then as an answer... It has already been established that the code within the if is executed.

Comment: is it though? He only noted that email has value. It could have the value "info@test.com" and still fail the if statement